# curl html form submit difficulties

Tags: html, curl

I try to login to the following form using cURL:

```html
<tr> <td height="24" width="92"><i><font face="Arial" color="#800000">Username</font></i></td>
<td height="24" width="300"><font face="Arial">
<input name=user size=32 maxlength=32 value='' style="width: 300; height: 24"></font></td> </tr>
<tr> <td height="24" width="92"><i><font face="Arial" color="#800000">Password</font></i></td>
<td height="24" width="300"><font face="Arial">
<input name=pass size=32 maxlength=32 type=password style="width: 300; height: 24"></font></td> </tr>
<tr> <td colspan=2 align=center height="70">
 <p style="margin-top: 5px"><font face="Arial"><input type=submit value='Login' onClick="return saveChanges()">
<input type=reset value='Clear'><br>
```

with the following command:

*curl --data "user=root&pass=XXX&submit=Login" http://10.62.76.4:9999/login.cgi --location*

the thing that confuses me is that the submit tag does not have a "name" and i don't know how to call it on the curl command. Plus i don't know what "onClick="return saveChanges()" means.

Answer (score 0):

> the submit tag does not have a "name" and i don't know how to call it on the curl command

It it doesn't have a name, then it won't be a successful control, and it won't be included in the data when you submit the form.

Thus, you don't need to include it in the cURL data.

> i don't know what "onClick="return saveChanges()" means.

It calls the `saveChanges` JavaScript function, which you didn't include in your code. That could do practically anything (including completely rewriting the form in the DOM or making a different HTTP request using Ajax).

It also returns the return value of that, which will prevent the form from being submitted if it is `false`.

Comment: I'm sorry i'm noob to web programming.

Here is the JavaScript function:

<Script language="javascript">
function saveChanges()
{
   if((document.loginform.user.value=="" && document.loginform.pass.value=="")||
      (document.loginform.user.value=="" && document.loginform.pass.value!="") )
   {   
      alert("Login error: Please try again.");
      document.loginform.user.focus();
      return false;
   }   
   return true;
}
</Script>

So what can i do to successfully submit the form.